# Appium/TestNG script on AWS device farm - could not find element

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, testng, appium, aws-device-farm

I am setting up my Appium/TestNG script in java on AWS Device Farm, using the tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html
After I compile and upload the 'zip-with-dependencies.zip' to AWS Device Farm and run the tests on a device, I get an error, that the first clickable element in the script could not be found.
So the Setup and Teardown suite are passing in the run, but the actual test fails every time:
[Failure Description on AWS Device Farm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gShIx.png)

My question is am I missing something from the configuration or is the script in need of any extra desired capabilities in order to actually execute the test on AWS Device Farm?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the version of the tested app with another one, seems like the previous one, where the element could not be found was popping out an android system message, which could not be clicked with the provided code, hence the searched element could not be found.
Another thing that device farm is not so good at - providing real time observations on the running tests, which could save a lot of time in this situations.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this for people who are still facing this issue.

You have to set up the `automationName` desired capability to the automation mechanism that you are using to automate the tests.

For me setting it up to `uiautomator2` works.

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:
1. Set element waiting time to be less than 60 seconds, because default Appium session will timeout after that.
2. Create a screenshot for the failure, check whether the element was loaded correctly.

Hope this would help:)

Thanks,
Hongda

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, setting the element waiting time to 30 seconds didn't work, and still couldn't be located. I am running the same tests locally with the appium server and emulator and the script runs every time.
One more thing I noticed, when compiling the "zip-with-dependencies.zip", with the 'mvn clean package -DskipTests=true' command and then trying to run the script locally to my appium server, they could not be executed.

Comment: Another thing I tried - I removed the clicking of any elements in the test script and only left some swipe actions and wd.closeApp(); and wd.launchApp(); at the end. Then the script is executed successfully and it passes in Device Farm. So the problem is the locating of the elements, could it be that the needed JARS are in the project's folder instead of in the "Maven Dependencies" when packaging?
The code I am using for the first of all elements is:
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("wt_sign_in")));
   Thread.sleep(1500);
   wd.findElementById("wt_sign_in").click();